# How to use operator LIKE between two columns in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have such a problem: I need to convert SQL query ("a.col1 like b.col2") to Scala and have no idea how to do it.
In "b.col2" there regular expressions such as "%smth%". The operator .like() in Scala works only with a column and a string, but not with both columns..
Are there any ideas?
Thanks <3

Comment: What library are you using? Add the name as a tag and show the code you have so far.

Comment: Is it Spark? Is it plain SQL with any library (Anorm, Slick, Doobie, Quill..)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you are talking about spark dataframes, you can write sql directly using `expr`:

```
    val df = Seq("foo" -> "bar", "baz" -> "%a").toDF("a", "b")
    df.filter(expr("a like b")).show
```